# How to open AWS SOC PDF reports on gnu/linux?

Tags: pdf

When opening the PDF generated by AWS for SOC-2 compliance in linux, evince is showing this error:
[image]

Sadly, there is no instructions for Linux and Adobe is not supported in this system.

Is it possible to see what is inside?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they used PDF as a ZIP file. So, first step is to show what is inside the PDF with `pdfdetach`, what can be installed with the `poppler-utils` package in ubuntu (`apt install poppler-utils`).

So, if our file is called `Service_Organization_Controls_(SOC)_2_Report_-_Current.pdf`, you can do:

```
pdfdetach 'Service_Organization_Controls_(SOC)_2_Report_-_Current.pdf' -list
```

This will list the internal content, that looks like:

```
$ pdfdetach 'Service_Organization_Controls_(SOC)_2_Report_-_Current.pdf' -list
2 embedded files
1: Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/AWS SOC 2 Report Apr-Sept 2020 - FINAL.pdf
2: Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/SOC2 Excel Provided by AWS Apr-Sept 2020.pdf
```

so we can extract the first document, but pdfdetach doesn't work because the directory doesn't exist, so it is required to create it by hand:

```
mkdir Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current
pdfdetach 'Service_Organization_Controls_(SOC)_2_Report_-_Current.pdf' -saveall
```

and now you can open `Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/AWS SOC 2 Report Apr-Sept 2020 - FINAL.pdf` as usual, but `Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/SOC2 Excel Provided by AWS Apr-Sept 2020.pdf` is just a container again:

```
pdfdetach "Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/SOC2 Excel Provided by AWS Apr-Sept 2020.pdf" -list
```

so you need to extract the real excel file, but this time it doesn't have spaces:

```
pdfdetach "Service Organization Controls (SOC) 2 Report - Current/SOC2 Excel Provided by AWS Apr-Sept 2020.pdf" -saveall
```

And you will get the excel file as well.